# Is anyone using the built in code-generation in VS2008 (.tt files)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-generation

Is anyone using the built-in code generation provided via text templates (using .tt files)? If so what are the main pro's/con's over other solutions like codesmith?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the T4 generation was pretty woeful in 2005. Apparently it's OK in 2008, but we went with Codesmith, as this was before 2005.

I assume that you will have seen the T4 editor? There's [a free edition from Clarius](http://www.t4editor.net/downloads.html). Also, there's a [great wealth of information](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) here in Oleg's blog.

My understanding is that you could get T4 to work and that it's fit for purpose, but that CodeSmith is a bit more mature.

Answer (score 2):

I would say before you use T4 look at your other options:
- CodeSmith
- XML/XSLT
- CodeDom
- other apps like CodeSmith

One thing that I do like is T4 is built into the compile process for free.

I second what Travis says about Oleg / Clarius.

You might also want to read this site as a resource:
[Kathleen Dollard at gendotnet](http://gendotnet.com/)

Her book: [Code Generation in Microsoft .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590591372)
If I remember correctly this mostly touches on XML/XSLT and CodeDom but might give you some ideas / contrast

A page of T4 resources from Hanselman:
[T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) Code Generation - Best Kept Visual Studio Secret](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)

Extra: [Kathleen Dollard on DotNetRocks](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=63)

I would say I have used T4 for some Code Generation but about the time I got the hang of it, I had moved towards using some Open Source frameworks to remove the need to write tedious code.

Answer (score 1):

T4 templates are used as the primary code generation technique used by the [Service Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/servicefactory/). Of course, they are also used by the DSL Tooklkit which is part of the Visual Studio SDK.

I've had very few problems with them, and the [Clarius T4 Editor](http://www.t4editor.net/downloads.html) makes them even more productive. The DSL toolkit (and thus the Service Factory) allow the template to iterate over a model to produce code. Other [directive processors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126315.aspx) allow a template to process any other sort of data (XML documents or schemas, database schemas or data).